# Autoscroll when UINavigationbar Prompt text is too long?

Tags: uinavigationbar, prompt, uinavigationitem

If I have a very long text as the prompt text, ex:

```
[[self navigationItem] setPrompt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a very long message which I want it to be scrolled. So that the user can read all the text."]];
```

How can I make it scroll automatically?

My solution is:

- Set the `promptText` to `nil`.
- Create a `UILabel` with the long text.
- Animate the `uilabel.position.x` and use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly Torn answers this question in his blog

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html